# GruntJS with multiple themes

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, grunt

I have a question about how to work with multiple stores and only one gruntfile.js file.

Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success using the Magento 2 way of organizing their grunt workflow in Magento 1 and iterating through them for each grunt task.

If you look at https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js

You'll see they list out each theme as well as the files specific to the theme, from here I just use require to include this file in each of my tasks (which I also store as individuals instead of just one giant grunt file).  See (https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/dev/tools/grunt/configs) for reference.

We've done this for about 9 months now and have had great success with it, especially when leveraging fallback to other themes.